# Need help aligning divs inside another div. Need them to be on the right side

Tags: html, css

[The image of the snowball should be in the topright corner. And i want 3 of them under each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8rTs.png)

I have tried it with float right. But it puts it like that out of the div. And when i put the playersumm div first it will appear in the top right corner. But when i do 3 of them. They will come next to each other inside of under each other,

html

```
<div class="playerInfo">
    <div class="playerChamp">
        <img src="profileIcon10.jpg" width="100" height="100" >
    </div>
    <div class="playerName">
        <label for="male">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="playerSumm">
        <img src="summ.png" width="40" height="40" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.playerInfo {
      height:120px;
      width:140px;
      background:blue;
        border:solid 1px black;
         position: relative;
  }

  .playerChamp {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background :red;
}

  .playerSumm {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background :green;
  float : right;
  display:inline-block

}

  .playerName {
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background :red;
}
```

Comment: What have you you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Tried the float right thing. The display inline-block. Set margin on 0. display fixed. position relative.  Sadly none of them worked out for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `div` with the class `playerSumm` at first. Like this :

```
<div class="playerInfo">
    <div class="playerSumm">
        <img src="summ.png" width="40" height="40" >
    </div>
    <div class="playerChamp">
        <img src="profileIcon10.jpg" width="100" height="100" >
    </div>
    <div class="playerName">
        <label for="male">Male</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And when i put the playersumm div first it will appear in the top right corner. But when i do 3 of them. They will come next to each other inside of under each other,  Then i still have the same problem. I want all of them inside the playerinfo div

Comment: Just wrap all of them inside another div and give that div `float: right;`. As simple as that.

Comment: It worked !!! Thanks a bunch. Any idea why it mathers what the order of my html code is ? Why does it put it outside when it on the bottom and puts it right when its above ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Sorry, I'm not really good at explaining. :D But the other way to do it would have been wrapping playerChamp and playerName inside one dive and making that parent dive `float: left;`. Hope that helps you figure the `float` out.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
  <div style="border:1px solid black; width:140px; height:120px; background:blue; overflow:hidden">
    <!-- left part with image and name -->
    <div style="float:left">
      <img src="profileIcon10.jpg" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:block" />
      <div style=" width:100px; height:20px; background :red;">MALE</div>
    </div>
    <!-- right part with snowballs -->
    <div style="float:left">
      <div style="width:40px; height:40px; background :green;">
        <img src="summ.png" style="width:40px; height:40px;"/>
      </div>
      <div style="width:40px; height:40px; background :green;">
        <img src="summ.png" style="width:40px; height:40px;"/>
      </div>
      <div style="width:40px; height:40px; background :green;">
        <img src="summ.png" style="width:40px; height:40px;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This works. But i am more curious about what i am doing wrong. Any idea what i did wrong ?

Comment: @JohnDoe as you can see i placed left part and right part in two divs with `float:left` and no `position` used

Answer (score 0):

In your code I can figure out few of the mistakes as follows:

1. For your parent div `playerInfo` you have set `border` property. the total width of your div element is 140px - 2px = 138px as the border width is included in width. So you need to use `box-sizing: content-box;` this was where the main mistake was.
2. You must use `display: inline-block;` for the `playerName` div.
3. You must set `float: left;` for `playerChamp` div.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajw7twcb/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="playerInfo">
  <div class="playerChamp">
    <img src="profileIcon10.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  <div class="playerSumm">
    <img src="summ.png" width="40" height="40">
  </div>
  <div class="playerSumm">
    <img src="summ.png" width="40" height="40">
  </div>
  <div class="playerSumm">
    <img src="summ.png" width="40" height="40">
  </div>
  <div class="playerName">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.playerInfo {
  height: 120px;
  width: 140px;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border:solid 1px black;
  //position: relative;
}

.playerChamp {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.playerSumm {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block
}

.playerName {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```